# How to manage click events made to an array of panels with C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, click, panel

I am working on an online checkers program and I have managed to draw the board and the checkers on each square with success. The only problem now is programming the click events ,I have code that responds to the clicks made to an individual panel to alter the background color to blue and the checker color to white, when a user clicks the same piece of panel , the colors are reversed back to the original. Now my problem is achieving this effect:: *If a user clicks on panelA and then the color altercation is applied, when a different panelB is clicked then the coloration applied to panelA should be restored back to the original like in the double clicking effect*.

**My Attempted Solution**

I initialized a `List<Panel> clicked_objects` object and used it to store the `Panel` element that was clicked, I expected the count of the list object to increase with each successive click but when I do a `MessageBox.Show(clicked_objects.Count.ToString())`, It always shows 1.
I needed to do this so that immediately a second clicked `Panel` is added to this list, I can check the count and color the Panel at `index 1(new Panel)` and decolorize the Panel at `index 0(previously clicked Panel)`. How can I achieve this? Click on One Panel removes the coloration on previously clicked element if any?

**Code**

```
public class Checkerpiece
    { 
        //declare a panel array for storing clicked Panels
        List<Panel> clicked_squares=new List<Panel>();
        //The object above can only hold two panel elements
        //colors of the rounded pieces
        Color color;
        //specify where the checker is drawn
        Panel target_square;
        //specify the center of the circle
        float center_x;
        float center_y;
        //specify the radius of the checker piece
        float radii;
        //define some foreground color that will be used to access the color of the checker
        Color foreground;
        //fill the details inside the constructor
        public Checkerpiece(Panel mypanel,Color color)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.target_square = mypanel;
            this.center_x = mypanel.Width / 2;
            this.center_y = mypanel.Height / 2;
            this.radii = mypanel.Width / 2;
            //register an onclick listener for our checkerpiece object
            this.target_square.Click += Target_square_Click;
           // this.target_square.MouseClick += Target_square_MouseClick;
        }

      
        private void Target_square_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clicked_squares.Add(target_square);
           //this keeps showing 1 no mater what panel I click
            MessageBox.Show(clicked_squares.Count.ToString());
         }
          public static void fillCircle(Graphics g, Brush b, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(b, centerX - radius, centerY - radius,
                     radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
        //implement a getter for the color used to used to draw the checker
        public Color getCheckerColor()
        {
            return this.color;
        }
  }
```

**Checker Board class**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Panel[,] _chessBoardPanels;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
      
       
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int tileSize = 100;
            const int gridSize = 8;
            var clr1 = Color.DarkGray;
            var clr2 = Color.White;

            // initialize the "chess board"
            _chessBoardPanels = new Panel[gridSize, gridSize];
            int count = 0;
            // double for loop to handle all rows and columns
            for (var n = 0; n < gridSize; n++)
            {
                for (var m = 0; m < gridSize; m++)
                {
                    // create new Panel control which will be one 
                    // chess board tile
                    var newPanel = new Panel
                    {
                        Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                        Location = new Point(tileSize * n, tileSize * m)
                      
                };
                    //register an event listener for each square

                   
                    // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
                    Controls.Add(newPanel);

                    // add to our 2d array of panels for future use
                    _chessBoardPanels[n, m] = newPanel;
                    //draw only the red checkers on top of the board
                    
                    // color the backgrounds
                    if (n % 2 ==0)
                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr1 : clr2;
                        //new Checkerpiece(newPanel, Color.Red).draw();
                    
                    else
                        newPanel.BackColor = m % 2 != 0 ? clr2 : clr1;
                    //draw a new checker piece
                    if (newPanel.BackColor==Color.White &&m<=3)
                        new Checkerpiece(newPanel, Color.Red).draw(); 
                       ;
                    if (newPanel.BackColor == Color.White && m > 4)
                        new Checkerpiece(newPanel, Color.Black).draw();
               
                }
            }
           
        }
}
```

**Output**

When I click on a piece, each coloration remains on the previously clicked item which should not be the case
[image]

**Goal**

How can I store the state of a clicked Panel and restore when a new Panel is clicked?

Comment: is this checkerPiece class a square? makes sense why it's only got 1 doesn't it?  its a single square.

Comment: seems like you'd need a board class?  where is that?

Comment: @TMcKeown, updating my code with the Board code

Comment: @TMcKeown, Yes the checker-piece class is a panel with logic to draw a filled ellipse on it

Comment: wouldn't clicked squares belong to the board?

Comment: @Yes they belong to the board which happens to be a form

Comment: but your question is why does the piece (a single square) only have 1 piece in it.  if the square is clicked you add to the list, so each squares list will only have entries when you click in that instance.  i guess i am not understanding what you want, i would think the board class would have the list of clicked pieces, your code has the piece tracking how many times someone clicks that SINGLE piece, right?

Comment: you should send the form to the piece, that way the piece can talk to the form.

Comment: @TMcKeown, question edited, now accessing the clicked object from the form as an array and then forming a loop to check which one was clicked is the problem

Comment: @TMcKeown, how can I access the children of the form as an array, use a loop to check if the clicked item matches and process?

Comment: you know what the clicked piece is, you don't need to find it.

Comment: the clicked event is fired, you cast sender as the control... thats the piece... what do you want to do next?

Comment: @TMcKeown, I did not know, you can cast sender as a control but I guess that is why we got Stackoverflow, we learn from each other.

Comment: @TMcKeown, this is what I want to do next, for example I have clicked panelA and then its been colored, I need when I click panelB then the coloration applied to panelA is restored to original and panelB is colored just like what would happen in a real checker's game

Comment: have the board keep track of Player1 current Piece and same for Player2 i would think... not sure, based on your code, as you set the boards Player1 property with the newPiece instance, set the "old" instance to Deselect() or something.

Comment: how do i get points??  i need to reword my answer so i get points...  =)

Comment: @TMcKeown, found a way, access the Panels from from1 as an array, loop through them while comparing their locaton.X and location.Y to target_square.Location.X, bingo :))

Comment: you shouldn't need to compare their X and Y, you have the objects..  i mean whatever works is fine.

Comment: @TMcKeown, your answer is most welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manage the pieces from the Board class, the list of Pieces can be checked by their reference, no need to "look" for a matching piece in the collection when you have the object via the clicked event.  Use the Board (Form) class to manage the Currently selected pieces and handle the Select/Deselect as you set those properties.

Comment: @T McKeown, the comparisons has a bug, posting the loop and see where I am doing it wrong, it succeeds in coloring the active clicked element and removing the coloration from the previously clicked \item but then whitens the rest of the board lol

Comment: i would need to  see more code.

Comment: @T McKeown, I edited the question with output picture included. Updating code so you can see how I accessed the elements from the Form1 and checked to see if it could color but its wrong

Comment: looks like you are looping thru the list and changing the color?  you should only need to Select() the current piece and Deselect() the prev piece.  You should add a Select() and Deselect() method to your Piece class, the board should call the appropriate method on the instance.  there is no need to loop thru all the pieces when all you are doing is Selecting/Unselecting (2 pieces)

Comment: @T McKeown, agreed. Looping through all the Panels makes the code slow, linear time complexity. Can you share some code I could implement in the Checkerpiece class to select and deselect a piece?

Comment: Give it a shot..  I gotta get back to work.  Code it.. try it.. I'll give you pointers

Comment: @T McKeown... Actually your vision is materializing in my brain, program select and deselect methods that use a panel as argument which in this case is the `target_square` object?

Comment: @T McKeown, Okay... Thanks

Comment: But.. on the clicked event... the piece should set the a property on the form. For example. The piece should know if it's a red piece or black right?  Do you tell your piece that? Does it know?  Then on the clicked event you could set a from property named CurrentBlackPiece to the clicked instance.

Comment: The form needs 2 properties added.. a prop named CurrentBlackPiece of the Piece type.. as well as a CurrentRedPiece

Comment: As you set the property value.. call the Deselect() on the piece that is being replaced.. call Select() on the newly selected Piece

Comment: @T McKeown, will let you know if I succeed or fail, yes the Checkerpiece type accepts two arguments, the panel on which it is being drawn and the color

Comment: @T Mckeown, how about I attach a mouse up and mouse down event to this, on mouse down, color panel, onmouse up decolorize